# Show #container when the page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript

Show #container gradually with the transition effect when the page is fully loaded?
Is there any javascript similar to this?

Thanks.!

Comment: there's a JS library that will make things banally easy: jQuery

Comment: Default `opacity:0`, add class in JS, use CSS transition `opacity:1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="container" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

javascript with jquery::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var _container = $("#container");
    _container.fadeIn();
});
```

javascript without jquery:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var _container = document.getElmentById("container");
    _container.style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time!